# In a script, check if standard input comes from a file or pipe

Tags: shell, shell-script, dash, stdin

I know this has been *poorly* covered previously, but those answers either lack explanation or don't apply.

Basically at some point my scripts needs check if a file is specified, if it was it will be used later as input.

```
[ -f "$1" ] && TINPUT="$1"
```

simple enough... Now if a file was not found, or not specified, I would have `TINPUT="-"` which would tell the later command to read stdin.

Here is my question... How do i get the script to die with error, if it was run without a pipe or without a file specified?

I'm using dash, the Debian POSIX complient shell, so I can't use Bashisms. I also prefer to use lists, over `ifs` but most `ifs` could be written in lists anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by “without a pipe”? If no file name is specified, read from stdin. What more do you want?

Comment: My question started with 'Here is my question..", meaning if the user just ran the script on its own.  So if data will never come through stdin, because it was never even invoked after a `|` in the first place.  If that specifically is not possible, which I believe it may not be, checking for data would also suffice.  basically i'd like the script to end and say, 'script needs a file name, or stdin', rather than just hanging with no output eternally as it now does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test whether standard input is a terminal:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  exec <"$1"
elif tty >/dev/null; then
  echo 1>&2 'Cowardly refusing to read data from a terminal.'
  exit 2
# else we're reading from a file or pipe
fi
```

Comment: I think I can take it from this point, thank you for your help.

Comment: Noting that GNU `tty` supports a [silent mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tty-invocation.html#tty-invocation): `tty -s` instead of `tty > /dev/null`