# Detect whether input is coming from the terminal

Tags: shell-script, read, stdin

I have a shell script that can read from a file or from standard input. Currently, if you don't give it a file or pipe text into it, it starts accepting input at the command prompt.

Instead, I would like to print "help" information in this scenario. Is there a standard way to do this? And if not, is there a way to detect standard input without affecting it? Or is there a way to detect where the would-be input is coming from?

I know that the `read` command can tell me whether there's input via its exit status. But it also *acts* on the input, affecting subsequent reads.

Comment: See [How to detect if input is from argument, file or terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15681), [In a script, check if standard input comes from a file or pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39950) etc

Comment: Looks like you want to detect whether stdin is a tty device or anything else rather than  to check whether there's any input. In `slow-to-start-cmd | your-script`, there won't be any input initially on your-script's stdin until the command starts to print something.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to check whether input is coming from a tty device. First, check whether args were given, then check `tty`.

```
if [ ! "$#" -gt 0 ] && tty -s ; then
  show_help
  exit 1
fi
```

From the documentation for `tty`:

> Print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.

If there isn't a terminal connected to standard input, `tty` gives a failure exit status. And the `-s` option suppresses output.